# How to block drag every element to my shopping list? (js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

`.produkt` is a product that I drag into the basket, and `.kontener_koszyka` is a basket and a place where I can drag an object.

The problem is that I can drag every element in my web app to the basket (links, images, other elements and they are counted as NaN).

so how to block in the code dragging every element on the page to my basket?

```
    $(".produkt").dragstart(function (evt) {
        evt.dataTransfer.setData("text", $(this).attr("id"));
});

$("#kontener_koszyka").drop(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var suma = 0;
    var przedmiot = evt.dataTransfer.getData("text");

    var nazwa = $("#" + przedmiot + " .nazwa").text();
    var cena = $("#" + przedmiot + " .cenaprzedmiotu").text();
    var id = $("#" + przedmiot + ".produkt").attr("id");

    var li = "<li class='produkt_w_koszyku'><b>" + nazwa + "</b> <span class='cena_w_koszyku'>" + cena + " zł</span> <span style='float: right; margin-right: 30px;' class='deleteitembasket'><i class=\"fas fa-times\"></i></span></li>";

    $("#koszyk").append(li);

    localStorage.setItem('item_id', (localStorage.getItem('item_id') || '') + id + ", ");
    localStorage.setItem('itemlist', (localStorage.getItem('itemlist') || '') + li);

    $("#koszyk .cena_w_koszyku").each(function () {
        suma += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });

    $("#cena span").text(suma.toFixed(2));
    localStorage.setItem('sumalist', suma.toFixed(2));
});
```